# Displaying NLog in date descending order

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++, nlog

I am using NLog with a VB.Net project:

```
Private m_logger As NLog.Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
```

Issues are populated in the log like this:

```
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString())
    m_logger.Error(ex, "ExtractCalendarInformation")
End Try
```

Now, this VB too is a console app that is used my another application which is written with Visual C++. If the parent app has detected that there are problems it displays the log file:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::ShowLogFile(CString strLogFile)
{
    if (PathFileExists(strLogFile))
    {
        CLogDlg dlgLog;

        CTextFileRead fileLog(strLogFile);
        CString strText = _T("");

        fileLog.ReadLine(strText);
        while (!fileLog.Eof())
        {
            strText.Trim();
            if (strText.IsEmpty())
                continue;

            dlgLog.AddLogEntry(strText, true);
            fileLog.ReadLine(strText);
        }

        dlgLog.SetErrorMode(true);
        dlgLog.DoModal();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the log file is in date ascebdung order and sometimes users send me screen shots and don't scroll.

[image: Log]

Is there anyway to display this error log from Nlog in fdate desending order? And I don't think it is OK to just read the file in reverse.

I include both VB and C++ tags since I might have to make changes in either tool.

---

I saw this question [Write records in descending order in NLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849770/write-records-in-descending-order-in-nlog). The thing is my C# tool uses `SimpleLogger` and that creates log folders in a folder and the log is named by date, and all items in that log are date descending. But I can't use `SimpleLogger` with VB.Net I don't think.

Comment: Why not just load the file into a `vector<CString>`, and then just use `rbegin()` for reverse iteration and inserting file-contents into the `dlgLog`.

Comment: Alternative check your `CTextFileRead` if there is a method to scroll down to the bottom after having loaded the file.

Comment: @RolfKristensen I'll investigate using the vector. That might be an easy solution. Thank you.

Comment: @RolfKristensen CTextFileRead is from herehttps://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7958/CTextFileDocument and it doesn't have a reverse read. I think I will try the other approach as a temporary workaround.

Comment: My suggestion about using the scrollbar in `CTextFileRead` does not require any reverse read. It just means scrolling to the bottom automatically after having loaded the file. Just like you can scroll to the bottom of a homepage in your web-browser.

Comment: @RolfKristensen Ah, I understand now. I'll have a look. There must be a way to post a message to the scrollbar to jump to the bottom. A suggestion here helps:https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?268933-CListbox-scroll-to-last-item. Later on this week I will try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to load the file into a `vector<CString>`, and then just use `rbegin()` for reverse iteration and inserting file-contents into the dlgLog.

Another option is to investigate how update scrollbar in `CTextFileRead` after having loaded the file, so scroll-button is moved down to the bottom.

---

## Update

I actually was using `CEdit` control to display the log contents. So in the end I used the following code to automatically scroll to the bottom:

`m_editLogData.LineScroll(m_editLogData.GetLineCount());`

Comment: Another thought ...  split each line at the delimiter and parse the date /time stamp. Only display if today’s date.